# How to get the relative path between two directories?

Tags: shell, make, gnu-make

Say I have a variable with a path `release/linux/x86`, and want the relative path from a different directory (i.e. `../../..` for current working directory), how would I get that in a shell command (or possibly GNU Make)?

Soft link support not required.

---

This question has been heavily modified based on the accepted answer for improved terminology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely not clear the purpose of it, but this will do exactly what was asked, using [GNU realpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html):

```
realpath -m --relative-to=release/linux/x86 .
../../..
realpath -m --relative-to=release///./linux/./x86// .
../../..
```

Comment: The problem here is that `realpath` is a nonstandard extension and not part of the UNIX/POSIX specs.

Comment: @schily and not all realpath(1) implementations support the `--relative-to` option.

Comment: If this ever becomes part of POSIX, it would first need to decide on a short option for that feature...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shell function which returns a relative path from source to
target directory using string manipulation only - through shell
parameter expansion - with no disk or net access. No pathname
[resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13)
is done.

Expects two parameters, source-dir and target-dir, both absolute
canonicalized non-empty pathnames, either may be `/`-ended, neither
need exist. Returns result in shell variable `$REPLY` as a relative path from source-dir to target-dir without trailing `/`, `.` if void.

Algorithm is from a 2005 comp.unix.shell posting which has now ascended
to [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20100910102150/http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2005-10/1256.html).

```shell
pnrelpath() {
    set -- "${1%/}/" "${2%/}/" ''               ## '/'-end to avoid mismatch
    while [ "$1" ] && [ "$2" = "${2#"$1"}" ]    ## reduce $1 to shared path
    do  set -- "${1%/?*/}/"  "$2" "../$3"       ## source/.. target ../relpath
    done
    REPLY="${3}${2#"$1"}"                       ## build result
    # unless root chomp trailing '/', replace '' with '.'
    [ "${REPLY#/}" ] && REPLY="${REPLY%/}" || REPLY="${REPLY:-.}"
}
```

Use as

```shell
$ pnrelpath "$HOME" "$PWD"
projects/incubator/nspreon
$ pnrelpath "$PWD" "$gimpkdir"
../../../.config/GIMP
$ pnrelpath "$PWD" "$(cd "$dirnm" && pwd || false)"
# using cd to resolve, canonicalize ${dirnm}
```

or, with [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax)s
sharing `scheme://authority`,

```shell
$ pnrelpath 'https://example.com/questions/123456/how-to' 'https://example.com/media'
../../../media
```

---

**Update** 2022-11-24

Skipping the `while` statement in the previous function will return
what `realpath --relative-base` does: a relative path from source to
target directory if target is in or below source, otherwise an
absolute path. Similar pre and post conditions apply.

```sh
pnrelbase() {
    set -- "${1%/}/" "${2%/}/"      ## '/'-end to avoid mismatch
    REPLY="${2#"$1"}"               ## build result
    # unless root chomp trailing '/', replace '' with '.'
    [ "${REPLY#/}" ] && REPLY="${REPLY%/}" || REPLY="${REPLY:-.}"
}
```

(end update)